# Can't connect to DB using node.js

Tags: sql

I am new to node.js and try to connect to my database. I am using VS 2019 and when debugging  while  connecting to the local  database (which is a copy from that on the server), it works fine and return the data but when I debug it when  refer to the database on the server it didn't work.

I got the following error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to SQL5075.site4now.net:1433 - 12924:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1994:

Can anyone help? Thank you

This is my code in VS2019:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('*', (req, res) =>  {
  
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
          //This connection works fine
         //user: 'sa',
         //password: 'xxxxxxx',
         //server: 'localhost', 
         //database: 'DB_9BD4_info'


// this connect to the server.
 
        user: 'DB_admin',
        password: 'xxxxxxx',
        server: 'SQL50.xxxxxxx.net',
        database: 'DB_9BD4_info' 
    };

    (async function () {
        try {
            let pool = await sql.connect(config)

            let result1 = await pool.request()                
                .query('select * from info')
   
            // console.dir(result1) 
            // send records as a response
            res.send(result1);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })();
    
    sql.on('error', err => {
        // error handler
        console.log(err);
    });

    
});

//start listening
var port = process.env.PORT || 5321;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Application started on ' + new Date());
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error. What worked for me was this config object:

```
const sqlConfig = {
  server: 'server',
  database: 'database',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  },
  options: {
    instanceName: 'instance name',
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    encrypt: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).